# Programmatically created UIBarButtonItem Not Launching Selector Action

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

Here is my `UIBarButton`:

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                            initWithTitle:@"+ Contact" 
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                   target:nil 
                                   action:@selector(showPicker:)] animated:YES];
```

Here is the code it's supposed to launch:

```
- (void)showPicker:(id)sender {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = 
     [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

When I launch the app and click on the  '+ Contact' `UIBarButton`, nothing happens. No errors, nada. I put in a breakpoint, and it never reaches the method referenced by the selector.

Am I doing something wrong in the way I'm calling the selector?

Thanks!

Comment: the selector is ok as soon as `showPicker` **does** take a parameter.

Comment: The solution was `target = self` instead of `target = nil`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The declaration of your button is missing something, namely the `target` parameter. Try this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"+ Contact" 
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                target:self 
                                action:@selector(showPicker:)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:item animated:YES];
```

This assumes that `showPicker:` is in fact in the same class that's adding the button to the navigation item.

The `target` parameter is the instance that should handle the event.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it! First time doing this programmatically. Thanks for  fix!

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer, then everybody wins! Thanks.

Comment: Yup, all done now. I was going to do it earlier, but it wouldn't let me (i.e., had 9 mins left before I could do it...). Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 3):

For those that are still having trouble with this, here is another solution that I have found:
Instead of doing this:

```
self.myBarButton = 
  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Woot Woot"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                  target:self 
                                  action:@selector(performActionForButton)];
```

Try something like this:

```
NSArray *barButtons = [self.myToolbar items];
UIBarButtonItem *myBarButton = [barButtons objectAtIndex:0];
[myBarButton setAction:@selector(performActionForButton)];
```

*Make sure you've added this `UIBarButtonItem` in the toolbar in Storyboard. (Or you could just programmatically create your own `UIBarButtonItem` before this set of code and add it to the **items** array of the UIToolbar.)

Somehow, **ageektrapped**'s solution did not work for me, although his solution is what I would rather use. Maybe someone more knowledgeable about UIBarButtonItems could comment on why one solution worked over the other?

Answer (score 2):

The "target" should be the object the selector belongs to, instead of nil.