# How do the click events on UIBarButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uicontrol, uicontrolevents

As `UIBarButton` is not inherited from `UIResponder/UIControl`, how do the click events on `UIBarButton` work?

Answer (score 3):

> Just create the UIBarButtonItem's `target` and `action` properties directly.

```
UIBarButtonItem *barListBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"yourTitle" 
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                            target:self action:@selector(btnClicked:)];   
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barListBtn;



-(void)btnClicked:(UIBarButtonItem*)btn 
{
NSLog(@"button tapped %@", btn.title);
}
```

**Choice-2**

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// first we create a button and set it's properties
UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
myButton.action = @selector(doTheThing);
myButton.title = @"Hello";
myButton.target = self;

// then we add the button to the navigation bar
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myButton;


}


// method called via selector
- (void) doTheThing {

NSLog(@"Doing the thing");

}
```

some additional [Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669520/programmatically-created-uibarbuttonitem-not-launching-selector-action)

Answer (score 0):

`UIBarItem` is an abstract superclass for items added to a bar that appears at the bottom of the screen. Items on a bar behave in a way similar to buttons (instances of `UIButton`). **They have a title, image, action, and target**. You can also enable and disable an item on a bar.

For more details checkout the link mentioned below:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem

**Swift:** 
 Add the below line in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action: "barButtonItemClicked:"), animated: true)
```

Function:

```
 func barButtonItemClicked()
    {
       print("Bar button clicked") 
    }
```